# Why use Localizable Strings in objective c vs Traditional Hash Maps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hashtable, localizable.strings

Question is basically in the title. Just looking for a simple answer

Comment: What do you mean by "traditional hash map"?

Comment: Pull in these strings into a traditional hashTable... Or in iOS speak, pack them in to separate NSDictionaries.

Comment: Oh god, don't use a static dictionary for this. All your classes are going to have to reference it!

Comment: Where have you ever seen a hash map used for this? I'm especially curious because you referred to that approach as the "traditional" way.

Comment: Why not a singleton dictionary?

Comment: Singleton's are a bad pattern to use in general. Do you really want every class in your app to be tied to your singleton?

Comment: I don't think Singleton is bad at all.. It all depends on the use case. If my HashTable will be the single central place for lookup, there is no problem in saying [LocalizedStrings sharedMapper] lookupKey

Comment: And now that class is unusable in another app that doesn't have the LocalizedStrings class.

Comment: But I think the crux here is HashTables load things into memory, in a mobile application memory needs to be conserved and is a valuable resource. So localizable strings seem to be a way to get quick, optimized lookup through the underlying OS itself

Comment: Who cares, I don't want it to be usable in another app?

Comment: Lol, well my string table is not to be used in another app... That has nothing to do with a design pattern but more of a use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `NSLocalizedString`, you don't have to write your own code to detect and load resources per locale, and instead rely on widely used and reliable code provided by the system. This saves time in development and debugging, and your code will be easier to understand by other developers familiar with the system.

Comment: Well are these strings indexed by the system in anyway, are the lookups efficient by the underlying OS?

Comment: Definitely more efficient, doesn't it happen at compile time? There is no lookup.

Comment: @AyBayBay Since it's a macro around an `NSBundle` method, its implementation and any optimizations are hidden. Are you running into performance issues with it?

Comment: @CrimsonChris it is a macro that resolves to a method call on the main bundle so it is dynamic.

Comment: Ah, so it is... Probably highly optimized.